# UICollectionView prevent cell re-use only for first cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, uicollectionview

Using UICollectionView with a custom UICollectionViewCell, I am trying to add some extra information only to the first cell. For this I am overriding the GetCell method

```
public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
```

This works fine and the first cell displays with the extra information. The problem is the cell is being re-used again in the CollectionView and the extra information is displayed again there.

How can I prevent re-use of the first cell in collection view?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't prevent reuse. The solution is to use reuse properly or use two different cell identifiers. One for the 1st row and a 2nd for all other rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few options:

- override prepareToReuse method of your UICollectionViewCell, and reset
  what you want in that method
- use different reuseIdentifiers for first
  and others cells
- use different prototypes/classes for first and other
  cells

To use different reuse identifiers:
If you do it in the storyboard via protorypes, create another prototype for a first cell and do something like this in your UITableViewDatasource

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FirstTableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UsualTableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if I go for the second alternative. How can I specify that the first cell should use a another identifier?

Comment: Updated answer, just copy current prototype cell in storyboard and then change reuse identifier http://cdn2.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/ReuseIdentifier.png

Comment: Thanks again for the example. For the first alternative to override the prepareToReuse method inside the cell. How can the cell access the index? How does the cell know it is the first cell?